# Validation messages displayed and cleared immediately

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces-3

I am using JSF 2.1.21 and my error messages are displayed and then cleared immediately when I press enter on the input text box. I have a javascript on the input which triggers a commandbutton.

```
<h:form>
<div><ice:messages /></div>
<ice:inputText  onkeyup="submitOnEnter(event);" value="#{bean.name}" maxlength="6" size="6">
                                <f:validator validatorId="stringValidator" />
</ice:inputText>
<ice:panelGroup>
   <ice:commandButton id="button" value="Go"    actionListener="#{myController.getReport}">
   </ice:commandButton>
</ice:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

**stringValidator:**

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws 
    ValidatorException {
if (!(((String) value).trim()).matches(REGEX_CONSTANT)) {
        ((UIInput) component).setValid(false);
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, 
                                        myMessage, null));
    } else {
        ((UIInput) component).setValid(true);
    }
```

**Update:**

```
function submitOnEnter(event) {
   var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;
   if(keyCode == 13) 
   {
           document.getElementById("myForm:button").click();
           return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you show the `submitOnEnter` function as that's clearly the cause of this problem? Are you familiar with basic HTTP/HTML/JS?

Comment: Please see update, yes I'm familiar and ready to learn anything from you.

Comment: There's the cause. You're triggering `element.click()` on an ajax-enabled button which performs its job through an `onclick`. I don't do ICEfaces and therefore I can't tell from top of head how the generated HTML representation look like, but theoretically, if ICEfaces did it right, you could fix this problem by using `element.onclick()` instead.

Comment: The `ice:inputText` adds it's own `onkeyup` function which makes a double submit, solved it by changing it to `h:inputText`. I should have investigated by looking at generated html. Thanks a lot BalusC!